# Selenium wait error javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium

I am submitting a form with selenium and phantomjs and then navigating back to the previous page by searching for a `br` element indicating that the form has been submitted.  Occasionally the timeout will exceed the 30s allotted time and an error will occur:
`TimeoutError: Waiting for element to be located By(xpath,//div[@id='ContactFormBody']/div/br)
Wait timed out after 30003ms`

I need to handle this error so that my program will not crash if this occurs.  Additionally if anyone wants to mention good documentation for selenium node.js, that would be great!

```
// code generating wait error
form.then(function(self){
    driver.wait(until.elementLocated(By.xpath("//div[@id='ContactFormBody']/div/br")), 30000)
    .then(function(){
        driver.navigate().back();
    });
});

// attempt at handling error
form.then(function(self){
    try{
        driver.wait(until.elementLocated(By.xpath("//div[@id='ContactFormBody']/div/br")), 30000)
        .then(function(){
            driver.navigate().back();
        });
    }
    catch(e){
        console.log("error occurred, script will continue.")
    }
});
```

Comment: Waiting for `br` that would indicate the form submission..does not sound very reliable..is there any other form submission indication on the page? Thanks.

Comment: I agree!  I was initially trying to wait/watch form the form fields to disappear which is another indication that the form was submitted.  Could not find any examples or documentation for this condition.

Comment: The `br` is a constant though its added in place of the form fields followed by text after form submission.

Comment: Alright, have you tried other browsers - is it consistently failing in chrome or firefox as well? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, actually the script take a cli argument that specifies the browser ( phantom, chrome, firefox )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify an error callback function as a *second argument* to `then()`:

```
driver.wait(until.elementLocated(By.xpath("//div[@id='ContactFormBody']/div/br")), 30000)
    .then(function() {
        driver.navigate().back();
    }, function (error) {
        console.log("Error happened!");
        console.log(error);
    });
});
```

This documentation page has a good overview of using promises in `WebDriverJS`:

- [Module selenium-webdriver/lib/promise](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/javascript/module/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.html)

Comment: Great answer, thanks for your help this is exactly what I needed!